# Assigning whole table to some other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets assume I have the following table

```
create table Article
(
  ART_ID        bigint not null auto_increment,
  ART_NAME      varchar(25) not null,
  ART_COST      decimal(8,2) not null,
  ART_DESC      text,
  primary key(ART_ID)
);
```

and also this table

```
create table Fruits
(
  FRUITS_ID     bigint not null auto_increment,
  FRUITS_TYPE   varchar(15),
  FRUITS_FROZEN timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  primary key(FRUITS_ID )
);
```

I want the Fruits table to have all the fields of the table Article. How can I implement this? Should I reference it by some relation or is there another trick?

Comment: What's the purpose of "having all fields from Articles in Fruits"?

Comment: Are you trying to change the structure of the `Fruits` table, or merely query the database for some resultset that combines the two tables?

Comment: Currently it is not clear how the fruit table relates to the article table. Is a Fruit an Article? Or do you just want to be able to store the same sort of data for Fruits?

Comment: @Shedal eggyal The purpose is to inherit all the fields of Article, and not harsh myself of writing ten times same code, 'cause I have other categories as well that require same structure of Article table.

Comment: Add `ARTICLE_ID` field to `Fruits` and reference it via a foreign key to ensure data consistency. But that means that you need a corresponding record in `Articles` for each fruit.

Comment: Aha, that is exactly what I was thinking. :) Thanks Shedal! You could write down the answer so I can declare it as proposed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need here is to add an `ARTICLE_ID` field to `Fruits`, and then reference it to `Articles.ART_ID` via a [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) constraint to ensure data consistency.

Note that this means that for each fruit, to have some "article" fields set, a corresponding record in `Articles` must exist. If you don't want article fields to be mandatory for a fruit, you can make the `ARTICLE_ID` field nullable. This still allows a foreign key to be defined, but it will only enforce a reference if the value stored in `ARTICLE_ID` is not `NULL`.